# Elastic search by date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "active": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "datum": {
              "lt": "17/08/16",
              "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "sort": {
      "datum": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me

> failed to parse search source. expected field name but got
>   [START_OBJECT]"}]

That is the first problem. Then I need to search in events and find only events in future or ongoing.

The events have 2 dates.

Datum = start of the event

Datum_to = end of the event (if it is empty the Datum is also ends date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Starting with version 2.0 there's no top-level `filter` clause anymore. Queries and filters have been merged into one, see the [Breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html).

To search for events that start in the future or have not yet finished, two `should` clauses should do the trick, e.g.:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "Datum": {
              "gt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "Datum_to": {
              "gt": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```